# Reasons for why x - 1 and x -1 gives different result in some languages

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

I assume the reason space makes a difference in F# is due to reserving a certain function, when minus is in front of a number without space, however what are the reasons for this? I can't seem to find any functions related to this

Comment: F#-specific questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry i guess i phrased it badly, my question was more related to what advantages or disadvantages there would be to include such features into a programming language in general

Comment: What are the reasons? I suppose is that the language designers designed it that way. And why? Because they thought it was a good idea. In Swift, the reason why whitespace around operators is sensitive is because it makes parsing possible without any knowledge of operators. Which is necessary because the compiler might actually not have any knowledge of operators.